# Firefox Developer Edition enable persistent logs

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I'm trying to get my breakpoints in Firefox Developer Edition to persist between sessions.
According to https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/settings/index.html#settings-common-preferences the Enable persistent logs option should do this but I don't see it here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/settings/index.html#settings-common-preferences it says:

*Note
If Common Preferences is not included in the Settings, Web Console logs can be persisted by using the ‘about:config’ url in browser address bar, searching for: ‘devtools.webconsole.persistlog’ then toggling this value to true*

I was able to do that and get it to work